# Como puedo mover elementos de una cola a otra en c++?

Tags: c++, dev-c++

El ejercicio dice que tengo que crear una cola C y al mostrar la cola C mover los elementos a una nueva cola y que en la cola C no quede ningún elemento

Por favor necesito de su ayuda
le he intentado de todo y aun no me da
espero que con este ejemplo puedan ayudarme

no se si si donde dice cloneQueue este bien

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <queue>
using namespace std;

struct nodo{
    int dato;
    struct nodo *sig;
};

struct cola{
    nodo *ultimo;
    nodo *primero;
};

void enqueue (struct cola &q, int valor){
    struct nodo *aux = new(struct nodo);
    aux->dato = valor;
    aux->sig = NULL;
    if(q.ultimo == NULL){
        q.ultimo = aux;
    }else{
        (q.primero)->sig = aux;
    }
    q.primero = aux;
}

int denqueue(struct cola &q){
    int num;
    struct nodo *aux;
    aux = q.ultimo;
    num = aux->dato;
    q.ultimo = (q.ultimo)->sig;
    cout<<"Elemento "<<num<<" ha sido eliminado"<<endl;
    delete(aux);
    return num;
}

void deletenqueue(struct cola &q){
    struct nodo *aux;
    while (q.ultimo != NULL){
        aux = q.ultimo;
        q.ultimo = aux->sig;
        delete(aux);
    }
    q.ultimo = NULL;
    q.primero = NULL;
}

void cloneQueue(struct cola c1, struct cola c2){
    struct nodo *a1;
    a1 = c1.ultimo;
    while (a1 != NULL){
        enqueue (c2, a1->dato);
        a1 = a1->sig;
    }
    a1 = c2.ultimo;
    while (a1!=NULL){
        cout<<"Dato: "<<a1->dato<<endl;
        a1=a1->sig;
    }
}

int main(){
    int valor;
    int opc;
    struct cola c1,c2;
    c1.ultimo = NULL, c1.primero = NULL, c2.ultimo = NULL, c2.primero = NULL;
    
    do{
        system("CLS");
        cout << "\tMenu" << '\n';
        cout << "\t[1]. Recibir Cola C" << '\n';
        cout << "\t[2]. Mostrar Elementos En Cola C" << '\n';
        cout << "\t[3]. Eliminar Elementos De La Cola C" << '\n';
        cout << "\t[4]. Mostrar Elementos En Nueva Cola" << '\n';
        cout << "\t[5]. Salir" << '\n';
        cout << "-> ";cin >> opc;
        
        switch(opc){
            case 1:
                cout<<"Ingrese Valor"<<endl;
                cin>>valor;
                enqueue(c1, valor);
                system("PAUSE");
                break;
            case 2:
                break;
            case 3:
                denqueue(c1);
                system("PAUSE");
                break;
                
            case 4:
                cloneQueue(c1,c2);
                system("PAUSE");
                break;
        }

    }while(opc!=5);
    /*enqueue(c1,81);
    enqueue(c1,23);
    enqueue(c1,3);*/
    getch();
}
```

Necesito ayuda por favor
el ejercicio dice asi
Escribir un programa que reciba una cola C de numeros enteros
y mueva sus elementos a una nueva Cola, pero manteniendo el orden
de salida de los elementos. Al finalizar la Cola C no debe contener elementos.

Comment: simplemente vacia tus datos de tu cola y insertalos en una nueva a medida que vas vaciando, `a.push(c.pop());`

Comment: Me podes brindar algún ejemplo?

Answer (score 1):

Puedes recorrer la cola con un ciclo `while` mientras no este vacía y para pasar al siguiente elemento tienes que quitar un elemento, así se moverá elemento por elemento hasta que quede vacía y eventualmente el ciclo `while` terminara

```
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    queue<string> origen, destino;

    // llenamos la cola origen
    origen.push("elemento 1");
    origen.push("elemento 2");
    origen.push("elemento 3");

    // recorremos la cola origen mientras no este vacia
    while(!origen.empty()){
        cout<<origen.front()<<"\n"; // mostrar elemento
        destino.push(origen.front()); //insertar en cola destino
        origen.pop(); // quitar elemento de la cola origen
    }

    // finalmente tenemos que la cola origen esta vacia
    // y la cola destino contiene los 3 elementos insertados

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: hola bro, mira he hecho esto pero no se como implementar el codigo tuyo

Comment: deje el ejercicio en un comentario arriba